# Scroll in the body and the space after the block

Tags: html, css, markup

I don't understand why there is a scroll in the **body** and a space after the block `.example`. According to my logic, I make the margin-bottom 100px and then subtract these 100px from the block height max-height: calc(100% - 100px);

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .example {
        padding: 20px;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 100px auto 0;
        max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    p{
        padding: 100vh 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>Lorem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into *wildly inherited margins* problem derived from the popular [collapsed margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) - [issue](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/) (which is better known for when two elements with vertical margins, the two *colliding* margins collapse into one) - not your *exact* case but same in nature.
Read more on [**w3.org Collapsing Margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Since you used `html, body {height: 100%}` and the tall `.example` element has margin-top 100% - **the `body` element moved, collapsed 100px down!** It basically "wildly" inherited (at least visually) those 100px margin.

An element with vertical margin can cause unwanted results with ancestors flow. One common way to fix this is to smartly avoid vertical `margin`, or to add `overflow: auto` to the ancestor that's being affected by that problem `html, body` in your specific case.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;    /* Why would you want this? */
  overflow: auto;  /* FIX for wild margins */
}
```

The **other solution** (I'm sure there are many others) is to not use `html, body {height: 100%}`
Rather `min-height` (if really needed) on html and body and `vh` (viewport height) unit  on the `.example` element

```css
html, body {
  /* min-height: 100%;  /* use min-height, but not needed */
}
.example {
  /* .... other styles */
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px); /* 100vh minus 100px margin-top */
}
```

Long story short - Be careful when using `margin`. I personally use it only when working with flexbox, or in the horizontal space (often when using inline-block elements) otherwise I always use wrappers with padding to create desired spacings which are perfectly controlled thanks to `box-sizing: border-box` (no need to calculate anything) - or when really necessary- I treat them with special care.

Comment: Yes, you right. I wrote my answer a second later

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `padding` on the `p` elements:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .example {
        padding: 20px;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 100px auto 0;
        max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="example">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem</p>
            <p>Lorem</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I asked about scrolling in the body

Answer (score 0):

Right answer its a Collapsing margins xD. To solve the problem, you can add one of the following to the body:

- border
- padding
- overflow

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan not sure what you mean by *widly inherited* but this is still the case of margin collapsing. Margin collapsing doesn't only happen between sibling elements but also between child and parent element (all explained within the same Sepc: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins *The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.* )

Comment: @TemaniAfif yep - those *are* collapsing margins in nature. (Added the link to my answer). The comment above is totally misleading. I'll remove it. Thx